# Intel AMT and host get different IP addresses via DHCP. How to fix?

Tags: dhcp, amt

I have a server that's recently been crashing occasionally in odd ways, so I decided to configure up Intel AMT on it in the hope of being able to reset it remotely when this happens.  For better or for worse, in the current set up, this server has a dynamic IP address, but things are configured so that DNS entries are updated if a new IP address is assigned.

Since I made this change, I've been having issues with AMT and the host OS (Ubuntu) ending up with different IP addresses assigned via DHCP; inevitably, this manifests itself in the DNS entries pointing to the IP address for AMT rather than the host OS, making it rather challenging to access the server (thank goodness for mDNS or I might be out of luck!).

My understanding is that when the host OS is running, AMT is just supposed to use the same IP address, but it seems like it's actually doing its own DHCP requests for some reason.

Any ideas how to resolve this situation?

Edit: out of technical curiosity and for some practical reasons, I'd really rather know how to make this work with dynamic IPs, although static IPs would theoretically resolve the issue I think.

Comment: What kind of server uses AMT?

Comment: @Grant you mean the model of the machine?  It's a Lenovo ThinkCentre M91p, with an i7-2600.  AMT version 7.1.3.

Comment: Ah, so by server, you mean desktop.  Gotcha.

Comment: @Grant By "server" I mean "runs 24/7 and provides services relied on by other computers and users".  But yes, it's desktop hardware.

Comment: Sounds like the real flaw here is how you update the DNS entries. And you haven't told us a lot about the mechanism you use for that. Ideally AMT should be using a different MAC and IP address from the host to avoid interfering with the OS' use of the network.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a normal behaviour. AMT operates independently of you operating system, so you may think of it as another device on your network and it should be connected to the network even when your server is powered off.

One way to do it is to use separate network adapter for your OS and leave embedded port to AMT.

Comment: I don't have any extra adapters, so they'll have to share.  But the "Note" box on [this doc page](https://software.intel.com/sites/manageability/AMT_Implementation_and_Reference_Guide/default.htm?turl=WordDocuments%2Fsetipv4dhcpandstaticipaddressmodes.htm) under item 3 makes me think they ought to be able to share?

Comment: Also [this other page](https://software.intel.com/sites/manageability/AMT_Implementation_and_Reference_Guide/default.htm?turl=WordDocuments%2Fautomaticsynchronizationofipaddresses.htm)

Comment: No, every AMT based computer I've seen took same IP address as underlaying OS.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to set up "[Shared FQDN](http://vpro.by/img/Shared-FQDN.png)".

> My understanding is that when the host OS is running, AMT is just
>   supposed to use the same IP address, but it seems like it's actually
>   doing its own DHCP requests for some reason.

Yes, Intel AMT makes its own DHCP requests (if there is [DHCP mode enabled](http://vpro.by/img/DHCP-Enabled.png)).

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to have a dedicated port for your AMT; you could always go with these options:

1.) Static IP address

or if you must use DHCP

2.) DHCP reservations which will tie your MAC address with a "reserved" IP address.

These should reliably get your system the same IP address between restarts/hangs/crashes (provided the physical NIC is the same).

Comment: I'd be fine with static IP for AMT, but unfortunately, my understanding from our network admins is that switching to a static IP (which they essentially implement via a DHCP reservation) will change the FQDN, and changing the FQDN of the host OS right now isn't a good option.  [The docs](https://software.intel.com/sites/manageability/AMT_Implementation_and_Reference_Guide/default.htm?turl=WordDocuments%2Fconfiguringtheintelamtipaddress.htm) seem to suggest that AMT doesn't like to have its IP be static while the host's is dynamic, though I'm unclear as to why this is.

Comment: I am having trouble seeing how a DHCP reservation affects the FQDN of anything. Could you clarify?

Comment: That's just how they seem to have it setup... When I request a static IP, I get `hostname.school.edu`, and when I say dynamic is okay, I get `hostname.dynamic.school.edu`.

Comment: do you have to connect via fqdn or pqdn? why not connect directly by IP of either statically or reserved addresses? I feel like I am not quite understanding your question here

Comment: I have half a dozen remote systems that connect via the FQDN and that I'd rather not have to risk driving out to visit if I miss a step in the re-configuration dance.  Also, I'm curious why AMT is not working as advertised, and "screw it, just use a static IP" doesn't tickle my curiosity.  But I _could_ do static IPs if there are no other options.